# Is member function virtual by default

Tags: scala, methods, jvm, overriding, virtual

Is member function virtual by default in scala? Is it different than Java in this matter?

When a method is overriden you have to explicitly state that, but there is no "virtual".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is member function virtual by default in scala?

Yes.

> Is it different than Java in this matter?

No, in Java methods are also virtual unless they're explicitly defined as `final`.

However Java is different from Scala in that Java doesn't require (or have) the `override` keyword in order to override methods - it does have an `@override` annotation though (since Java 1.5) and gives a warning when you override a method without that annotation.

Comment: @lukas Yes. You can define a final method using `final def methodName(...) = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is member function virtual by default in scala?

Yes.

> Is it different than Java in this matter?

No. However it is different from C++ or C#.

Whether this is a good or bad idea is highly argumentative.